# Trouble to go main page when choose option from navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Im My app Im having trouble in on part,

Im created a navigation Drawer, having 8 option. when i click my 1st option it goes to Main page(Main page name is DriverDashboard).
when i click second option to goes to other class. etc.

**Problem** : At first , i choose my 1st option it doesn't goes to my main page. but  choosing 2nd or 3rd or some other option after that i choose my 1st option it goes to main page. 
          But directly i choose 1st option it doesn't go to main page . only show white color screen. i think Content_frame can't remove in that time.How can i recover this problem.

Here Java Code,

```
 mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            cd = new ConnectionDetector(NavigationDrawerNew.this);
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                     break;
                case 1:
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DashBoardDriver());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DriverRadius());

                    break;
                case 3:
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new TripSummeryList());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new BankDetails());
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new PaymentDetails());
                    break;
                case 6:
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ChangePassWord());
                    break;
               /* case 7:
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsLanguageChange());
                    break;*/
                case 7:
                    Intent feedback_intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerNew.this, FeedBackPage.class);
                    startActivity(feedback_intent);

                    break;
                case 8:
                    Intent about_intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerNew.this, AboutUs.class);
                    startActivity(about_intent);

                    break;
                case 9:

                    showBackPressedDialog(true);
                    break;

            }
            ft.commit();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawer);

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: put your dashboardDriver to case 0:

Comment: can you tell me in which class are you calling navigation drawer ?

Comment: when you click first item which position is selected first or zero?

Comment: @vikassingh   Home to driverdashboard

Comment: @Bek Case 1 --> Home option to driverdashboard

Comment: Can you add this code= ft.addToBackStack(null);

Comment: You open your app -> Blank screen is shown -> You click on home -> Nothing happens -> You click on other option -> It works -> Click home again -> dashboard is shown.

Is that your problem? And why is your case 0 `break;`?

Comment: Correct view : Click home it show dashborad. MY problem: click home --> White screen shown...... click on other option - > it works.--> click home again --> dashborad shown (in this case its working fine).

Comment: @Arun I've put a link below.. Try to make like this https://github.com/droidapp/customDrawerListView/tree/master/app/src/main

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing some

```
Log.v("Debugging Tag","Is this printed ?");
```

in case 1, and try also to switch the case 1 and case 2 to see if it could replace

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
switch (position) {

        case 0:
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked position is "+ position);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DashBoardDriver());
            break;
        case 1:
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked position is "+ position);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DriverRadius());

            break;
        case 2:
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked position is "+ position);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new TripSummeryList());
            break;
        case 3:
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked position is "+ position);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new BankDetails());
            break;
        case 4:
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked position is "+ position);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new PaymentDetails());
            break;
        case 5:
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked position is "+ position);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ChangePassWord());
            break;
        case 6:
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked position is "+ position);
            Intent feedback_intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerNew.this, FeedBackPage.class);
            startActivity(feedback_intent);

            break;
        case 7:
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked position is "+ position);
            Intent about_intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerNew.this, AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(about_intent);

            break;
        case 8:
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked position is "+ position);
            showBackPressedDialog(true);
            break;

    }
```

Comment: clicked position is 1

Comment: Case 1 working but content_frame cant able to remove that is tha problem. if we go case 2 and then click case 1 means, that time case 1 goes to driverdashboard page. My problem is when i choose case 1 directly means, it show white page. i think content_frame not removing..

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's onCreate, add this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DashBoardDriver());
ft.commit();
mDrawerList.setItemChecked(1, true);
```

Comment: So after adding this in onCreate, still blankScreen?

Comment: You have to initialise mDrawerList before this code

Comment: same white screen will appear

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lst_menu_items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_listview);  

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DashBoardDriver());
        ft.commit();
        lst_menu_items.setItemChecked(0, true);

    }
```

And Here Your ListView OnItemClickListener

```
lst_menu_items.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {


                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    switch (position) {

                        case 0:
                         ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DashBoardDriver());
                            break;
                        case 1:
                             ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DriverRadius());
                            break;

                        //.....
                    }
                    ft.commit();
                    lst_menu_items.setItemChecked(position, true);

                }
            });
```

Comment: @Arun call this in onCreate method  ` FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DashBoardDriver());
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);`  and set ` ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DashBoardDriver());` in case 0

Comment: And You Can also check Developer docs https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

@vikas singh

Here xml code,

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffffff"

        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/drawer_listview">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"


        />


    <com.plowfourme.driver.widgets.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/verion_no"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Version 2.0"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#c9c9c9"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:typeface="sans"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#f7f7f7"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/verion_no"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```